# Not listing the files and folders inside the azure file share

Tags: azure, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell, azure-file-share

```
$resourceGroupName = "xbackbonektadevmc-rg"
$storageAccName = "xfssaktamc601"
$fileShareName = "imagingcenter"
$directoryPath = "Software\KTA OPMT\KofaxTotalAgility-7.11 Software\KofaxTotalAgility-7.11.0.11_OPMT"

# Define the function to list directories and files recursively
Function GetFiles 
{ 
    param (
        [string]$path
    )

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Lists directories and files under $path.."   

    ## Get the storage account context 
    $ctx = $storageAccount.Context

    # Retrieve all files and folders under the file share
    $filesAndFolders = Get-AZStorageFile -Context $ctx -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $path

    ## Loop through files and folders 

    foreach($item in $filesAndFolders) 
    { 
        # Check if the item is a directory
        if ($item.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFileDirectory")
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Folder Name: " $item.Name 

            # Recursively call GetFiles function to list contents of subfolders
            if ($item.Path -like "$directoryPath\*") {
                GetFiles -path $item.Path
            }
        }
        else
        {
            # Display file name
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "File Name: " $item.Name 
        }
    } 
} 

# Start listing files and folders from the KofaxTotalAgility-7.11.0.11_OPMT folder

GetFiles -path $directoryPath
```

I have tried executing the script it just display the name of the folder KofaxTotalAgility-7.11.0.11_OPMT but it is not listing the files and folders inside it
can you please help me adjust this script

Comment: Can you include the line, how you are getting `$ctx = $storageAccount.Context`?

Answer (score 0):

> Not listing the files and folders inside the Azure file share.

You can use the script below to list both folder and file names using Azure PowerShell.

**Script:**

```
$resourceGroupName = "<Your-resource-grp name>"
$storageAccountName = "your-storage-account-name"
$fileShareName = "<Your-file-share-name>"
$directoryPath = "files/sample1"

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

Function GetFiles 
{ 
    param (
        [string]$path
    )

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Lists directories and files under $path.."   
    $ctx = $storageAccount.Context

    $filesAndFolders = Get-AZStorageFile -Context $ctx -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $path |Get-AZStorageFile
    foreach($item in $filesAndFolders) 
    { 
        if ($item.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFileDirectory")
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Folder Name: " $item.Name 
        }
    }
    foreach($item in $filesAndFolders) 
    { 
        if ($item.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFile")
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "File Name: " $item.Name 
        }
    }
} 

GetFiles -path $directoryPath
```

The script above lists all directories and files under a specified path in an Azure file share. It takes in the **`resource group name,`** **`storage account name`, `file share name`, and `directory path`** as parameters. The script retrieves the storage account context and uses the `Get-AZStorageFile` cmdlet to list the directories and files.

**Output:**

```
Lists directories and files under files/sample1..
Folder Name:  sample2
Folder Name:  sample3
File Name:  05-03-2024.html
File Name:  78089305.html
File Name:  78106201.html
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get-AzStorageFile (Az.Storage) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefile?view=azps-11.4.0)